# A general pencil $\{t_0F+t_1G\}$ of plane quartics consists entirely of smooth and nodal curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $F,G$ be general plane quartics. It states in Harris, Morrison, Moduli of Curves, pg. 182, that the pencil fixing a value of $t$ for $H(X,t)=t_0F(X)+t_1G(X)$ yields either a smooth or irreducible, nodal curve.

**Question:** Why is this the case? Specifically, when it is not smooth, how do we know the singularity is a node?

Comment: In the parameter space of plane quartics $\mathbb P^N$, the discriminant locus $D$ is a hypersurface. A smooth point of $D$ corresponds to a curve with one node. Now, take a general pencil in $\mathbb P^N$, it intersect $D$ at smooth points.

Comment: Sorry but what is the discriminant locus $D$? I saw this further in Moduli of Curves but couldn't find a definition.

Comment: It is the set of all singular quartics.

Comment: @AG learner Thanks! And why does a smooth point of $D$ correspond to a nodal curve?

Comment: Good question! See Proposition 7.20 in [3264 and all that](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/joeharris/files/000-final-3264.pdf)

Comment: In general, I would recommend spending a good bit of time with *3264 and All That* before diving into *Moduli of Curves*. 7 or 8 years ago I was in a similar position, reading the latter first, and was constantly thrown off by facts like this that Harris and Morrison expect the reader to know off-hand.